# Logging with Laravel Mix?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-elixir, laravel-mix

With elixir I used to be able to log via:

```
elixir.Log.heading('Hello')
elixir.Log.message('something is happening');
```

How can I achieve the same with mix? I've tried mix.log with no luck.